# How do I apply gsub to replace characters not in a range

Tags: regex, r

Quicky

```
gsub("[a-c]",".", txt)  # replaces all a,b,c with a period

gsub("^a",".", txt)     # replaces all characters other than a with a period
```

How do I replace all characters other than a,b,c with period
Thought it would be matter of placing brackets correctly but cant seem to hit on solution

cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
> gsub("[^a-c]", ".", letters[1:10])
 [1] "a" "b" "c" "." "." "." "." "." "." "."
```

See here for details: http://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html

Comment: and quick it was. Thanks for link as well. I'll set as answer when allowed